# Larave where ONLY has

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to do a request to find invoices (parent table) that have ONLY relation (intervention_invoicing) intervention_invoicing.status_id = 3.
I only find a solution to find invoices with at least 1 relation where status_id = 3 but that is not the thing I need.
Maybe you will help me

[image: Here is an exemple I don't want to get]

[image: Correct exemple]

Comment: Please add sample table data to your question.

Comment: try the inverse ... whereDoesntHave relation status_id != 3

Comment: whereDoesntHave is a good solution...I don't know why I didn't think about this before. Thank you for your help !!